# How to compile the extended character in C++ using GCC?

Tags: c++, character-literals

The following code fails to compile using GCC:

```
int main()
{
    for(int j=0; j<80; j++) //for every column,
    { //ch is ‘x’ if column is
        char ch = (j%8) ? ‘ ‘ : ‘x’; //multiple of 8, and
        cout << ch; //‘ ‘ (space) otherwise
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It should print:
**x x x x x x x x x**

But I get the following error:

> error: extended character ‘ is not valid in an identifier

Comment: Please specify the exact error you get. You probably need to replace `‘` and `’` with `'`.

Comment: **error: extended character ‘ is not valid in an identifier**

Comment: (1) The error should be a part of your question - please [edit] it. (2) As I wrote, replace  `‘` and `’` with `'` (the single quote character you used is not the proper one).

Comment: this should print : **x x x x x x x x x**

As j cycles through the numbers from 0 to 79, the remainder operator causes the expression (j
% 8) to become false—that is, 0—only when j is a multiple of 8. So the conditional expression
(j%8) ? ‘ ‘ : ‘x’
has the value ‘ ‘ (the space character) when j is not a multiple of 8, and the value ‘x’ when
it is.
You may think this is terse, but we could have combined the two statements in the loop body
into one, eliminating the ch variable:
cout << ( (j%8) ? ‘ ‘ : ‘x’ );

Comment: Your last comment is still using the wrong single quote character. Try to use `'`.

Comment: I can't find this to fix it, lol

Comment: What can't you find ?

Comment: @wohlstad the wrong single quote character

Comment: Instead of `‘ ‘ : ‘x’`, you should use `' ' : 'x'`. Note the different single-quote.

Comment: @wohlstad yes this was actually the issue, your comment is the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
char ch = (j%8) ? ‘ ‘ : ‘x’;
```

You are using the wrong single-quote.
The proper one is `'`, i.e.:

```
//----------------V-V---V-V-
char ch = (j%8) ? ' ' : 'x';
```

This is specified in the [Character literal documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal).